# How to turn off Safari autofill in webpage source

Tags: html, safari

I have an advanced search form that terms/rows can be added to dynamically.  I have noticed that the larger the form, then slower the form is when you click in a text field.  Sometimes, you click in a text field and wait around 2 seconds on a moderately sized form before anything typed shows up.

It only happens when the text field is initially empty - and only in Safari.

I discovered that if I go into the Safari Preferences, go to the "Autofill" tab, and turn off all "Autofill web forms" checkboxes, the form is zippy - no lag.  Apparently, Safari is trying to figure out how to suggest things to enter, like info from my contact card, usernames and passwords, credit cards, etc...

This advanced search form doesn't seem relevant to any of that (unless it tracks repeatedly entered search terms...?).  So here are my questions:

1. Is there a way to tell Safari to not look for autofill possibilities, so that my form doesn't have this lag in Safari?
2. If #1 isn't an option, is there a way to make Safari's suggestions more efficient - so it can more quiickly figure out that there's nothing to suggest?

Regarding #2, my text fields have no label.  The "labels" are the values chosen in the preceding select lists.  Here's an example:

[image]

Note that after the 1-2 second delay, the autofill icon appears in the field:

[image]

Could adding hidden labels make Safari's autofill feature more efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried and failed with various "solutions" I found here on stack:

- Set attribute autocomplete="off" in both the form and input elements
- Added a hidden label both above and below the input tag
- Added a class name suggesting the input field type
- Tried a [javascript solution](https://github.com/terrylinooo/disableautofill.js)

None of them worked.  I still experienced a delay between clicking in a field and being able to enter text - and the user icon still presented phone number suggestions from my contact card.

I read an old, but otherwise helpful [article about how to coax autofill to fill in the correct information](https://cloudfour.com/thinks/autofill-what-web-devs-should-know-but-dont/).  It didn't mention the solution I stumbled upon, but it inspired me to try it...

I added a placeholder attribute to the text input in my django form class:

```
    val = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "search term"}))
```

And that did it!  Now when I click in a search term field (which now shows "search term" in light gray - which is grudgingly OK with me), I can enter text right away and the autofill icon does not appear!:

[image]